# projective subspaces over a field of  elements

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

How many -dimensional projective subspaces in $\mathbb{P}_n$  over a field of  elements?

There are as many  -dimensional projective subspaces in $\mathbb{P}_n$ as  (+1)-dimensional subspaces in V (dim(V)=n+1) over a field of  elements. If it's right then the answer is $\frac{(q^{n+1}-1)(q^{n+1}-q)…(q^{n+1}-q^{k})}{(q-1)^(k+1)}$. Is it correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct idea, but the number of subspaces is wrong. The subspaces of dimension $m$ in a $\Bbb K^n$ are naturally in bijection with the classes of the equivalence relation $$A\sim B\iff \exists G\in\operatorname{Gl}(m,\Bbb F),\ B=AG$$

over the set of $n\times m$ matrices of rank $m$, and therefore the cardinality is $$\left\lvert \operatorname{Gr}(m,\Bbb F_q^n)\right\rvert=\frac{\prod_{j=0}^{m-1}(q^n-q^j)}{\prod_{j=0}^{m-1}(q^m-q^j)}=\prod_{j=0}^{m-1}\frac{q^n-q^j}{q^m-q^j}$$

In your case, $n:=n+1$ and $m:=k+1$.